# PHP/PDO::commit doesn't work in "try" block

Tags: php, exception, transactions, pdo

When I put "PDO::commit()" method into "try" block it doesn't work and I get no "commit" even if the SQL-code is OK.

```
$conn->dbh->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $conn->dbh->prepare('some SQL-code');

$stmt->bindValue(...);

try 
{ 
    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->dbh->commit();
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $dbh->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But if I put it after "catch" block everything works fine.

```
...
try 
{ 
    $stmt->execute();
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $dbh->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$conn->dbh->commit();
```

Is this is an expected behaviuor and why PDO::commit() does not work inside "try" block?

Just want to clarify it for myself because I've spent the whole two hours to find a solution to this problem and I'm not sure if that solution is the right one.

---

Here's the code:

```
Class Connection
{
public $dbh;
private static $instance;

private function __construct()
{
    $config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
    $dsn = $config['db.dbms'] . ':host=' . $config['db.host'] .
           ';dbname='    . $config['db.dbname'] .
           ';port='      . $config['db.port'] .
           ';connect_timeout=15';
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $config['db.user'], $config['db.password'], array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance))
    {
        $object = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance = new $object;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
}

Class NestedSet
{
public function insertAsLastChildOf ($parentnode)
{
    $fields = '';
    $params = '';

    $conn = Connection::getInstance();

    $conn->dbh->beginTransaction();

    foreach ($this->_modelfields as $field => $type)
    {
        $fields .= '`'.$field.'`, ';
        $params .= ':'.$field.', ';            
    }

    $stmt = $conn->dbh->prepare('UPDATE `' . $this->_tablename . '`
                           SET `rgt` = `rgt` + 2
                           WHERE `rgt` >= :parentnodergt;


                           UPDATE `' . $this->_tablename . '`
                           SET `lft` = `lft` + 2
                           WHERE `lft` > :parentnodergt;


                           INSERT INTO `' . $this->_tablename . '`  
                              (' . $fields . '
                               `lft`,
                               `rgt`,
                               `level`)
                            SELECT  
                                ' . $params . '
                                `rgt` - 2, 
                                `rgt` - 1, 
                                `level` + 1                                    
                            FROM `' . $this->_tablename . '`
                            WHERE `id` = :parentnodeid;');

    foreach ($this->_modelfields as $field => $type)
    {
        $pdoparam = (stripos($type, 'int') === 0) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR;
        $stmt->bindValue(':'.$field.'', $this->$field, $pdoparam);
    }

    $stmt->bindValue(':parentnodergt', $parentnode->rgt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':parentnodeid', $parentnode->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    try
    {
        $stmt->execute();
        $conn->dbh->commit();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $conn->dbh->rollBack();
        echo $e->getMessage() . '<br/> file - ' . __FILE__ . '<br/> line - ' . __LINE__ . '<br/>';
    }

    unset($stmt); 
}
}
```

I've tried to rewrite the code so that I have one query per prepared statement. In that case everything works fine - I have the code executed if there are no errors and get an exception and the rollback otherwise.

Here's the code

```
    $stmt_1 = $conn->dbh->prepare('UPDATE `' . $this->_tablename . '`
                            SET `rgt` = `rgt` + 2
                            WHERE `rgt` >= :parentnodergt;');
    $stmt_1->bindValue(':parentnodergt', $parentnode->rgt, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt_2 = $conn->dbh->prepare('UPDATE `' . $this->_tablename . '`
                            SET `lft` = `lft` + 2
                            WHERE `lft` > :parentnodergt;');
    $stmt_2->bindValue(':parentnodergt', $parentnode->rgt, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt_3 = $conn->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `' . $this->_tablename . '`  
                              (' . $fields . '
                               `lft`,
                               `rgt`,
                               `level`)
                            SELECT  
                                ' . $params . '
                                `rgt` - 2, 
                                `rgt` - 1, 
                                `level` + 1                                    
                            FROM `' . $this->_tablename . '`
                            WHERE `id` = :parentnodeid;');

    foreach ($this->_modelfields as $field => $type)
    {
        $pdoparam = (stripos($type, 'int') === 0) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR;
        $stmt_3->bindValue(':'.$field.'', $this->$field, $pdoparam);
    }

    $stmt_3->bindValue(':parentnodeid', $parentnode->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    try
    {
        $stmt_1->execute();
        $stmt_2->execute();
        $stmt_3->execute();
        $conn->dbh->commit();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $conn->dbh->rollBack();
        echo $e->getMessage() . '<br/> file - ' . __FILE__ . '<br/> line - ' . __LINE__ . '<br/>';
    }
    unset($stmt);
```

Does this mean that PDO::prepare() should not be used with multiple queries?

I'm asking because I haven't found anything about that in the PDO manual.

Comment: Have you enabled exception throwing for your PDO instance? `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Yes, I have put that in the __construct() in the Connection class (Singleton): `$this->dbh = new PDO(...);$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` And if I have errors in the SQL-code I get an Exception thrown.

Comment: Try to provoke the exception and see if that really works.

Comment: Also, which *specific* exception do you expect to be thrown if the transaction fails? In your code it's `Exception` which is not specific. So could you add some reference?

Comment: It's strange but I do not get an exception even if I have an error in the SQL-code. So I need to revise my code.

Comment: I have multiple queries in a single transaction. So, it seems that when the first query is valid ("UPDATE ..."), I get an automatic commit even inside a transaction. But when the first query contains error I do get an exception.

Comment: Can you post all your code? Or at least the PDO calls? Otherwise it's impossible for us to see what may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your query. It's not working in the t/c block because `execute()` is causing an error, making it so the exception is thrown before the `commit()` call. And the only reason it works when you move it after the t/c block is because it's a procedural step-thru at that point. Try tailing your error log.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($stmt);` after the initial assignment? Those multiple query statements are messy, I'm curious if it works.

Comment: I've tried to do one query at a time and it works. And in that case if there are errors in the query I get the exception thrown. For example if I leave only the INSERT query and try to make a duplicate entry for the PK field I get the following exception `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5th' for key 'reference'
file - C:\...\classes\NestedSet.php
line - 187`

Comment: When you had them as individual statements, did you have them all within the same transaction?

Comment: Yes, several prepared statements (one query per prepared statement) within one transaction work and one prepared statement with several queries inside does not work.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'resolve'. On the one hand yes. I've just split that prepared statement with multiquery into several statements (one query per prepared statement) inside one transaction. On the other hand no. I've not been able to make a single prepared statement with multiquery work inside a transaction. Apparently this is a PDO bug. Here is a [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614876/pdo-bug-prepare-with-multi-queries-doesnt-work-inside-a-transaction) about this problem.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the update. I've only ever done what you ended up having to do, guess we'll see if they address it.